# Trying to upload an image using MERN getting 400 bad request error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, react-redux

Hi hoping someone can help.  Building a project using MERN and it needs to have file upload function.  Have tried to implement various solutions and don't seem to be getting anywhere.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my express routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
// bring in normalize to give us a proper url, regardless of what user entered
const normalize = require('normalize-url');
const checkObjectId = require('../../middleware/checkObjectId');

const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');


const Profile = require('../../models/Profile');
const User = require('../../models/User');
const Post = require('../../models/Post');



const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, res, cb) {
      cb(null, './files');
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${new Date().getTime()}_${file.originalname}`);
    }
  }),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000 // max file size 1MB = 1000000 bytes
  },
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$/)) {
      return cb(
        new Error(
          'only upload files with jpg, jpeg, format.'
        )
      );
    }
    cb(undefined, true); // continue with upload
  }
});

// @route    POST api/profile/upload
// @desc     Upload profile image
// @access   Private

router.post(
  '/upload',
  upload.single('file'),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log('Hello')
      const { path, mimetype, originalname } = req.file;

      const profileFields = {};
      profileFields.user = req.user.id;
      if (path) profileFields.image.path = path;
      if (mimetype) profileFields.image.mimetype = mimetype;
      if (originalname) profileFields.image.originalname = originalname;

      let profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
        { user: req.user.id },
        { $set: profileFields },
        { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
      );

      return res.json(profile);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log('help')
      res.sendStatus(400).send('Error while uploading file. Please try again later.')
    }
  },
  (error, req, res, next) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
  }
);
```

here is my model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  image: {
    origianlname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    path: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mineType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
},
  topics: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'topic',
    }
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

I have set up a folder called files in my backend

Front end

actions file

```
//Upload profile picture

export const uploadImage = (file) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    await axios.post('api/profile/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });
    dispatch(setAlert('Profile picture uploaded successfully', 'success'))
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
    });
  }
}
```

Upload.js component file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { uploadImage } from '../../actions/profile';


const Upload = ({ errors, dispatch }) => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setErrorMsg(errors);
    }, [errors]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setErrorMsg('');
    }, [])

    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        setFile(file);
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (file) {
            setErrorMsg('');
            dispatch(uploadImage(file));
            setIsSubmitted(true);
        }
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {errorMsg && errorMsg.upload_error ? (
                <p className="errorMsg centered-message">{errorMsg.upload_error}</p>
            ) : (
                isSubmitted && (
                    <p className="successMsg centered-message">
                        Photo uploaded successfully
                    </p>
            )
            )}
            <Form
            onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
            method="post"
            encType="multipart/form-data"
            className="upload-form"
            >
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Choose photo to upload</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type ="file" name="file" onChange={handleOnChange} />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button
                variant="primary"
                type="submit"
                className={`${!file ? 'disabled submit-btn' : 'submit-btn'}`}
                >
                Upload
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    file: state.file || [],
    errors: state.errors || {}
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Upload);
```

Reducer file

```
import {
  GET_PROFILE,
  PROFILE_ERROR,
  CLEAR_PROFILE,
  GET_PROFILES,
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  profile: null,
  profiles: [],
  repos: [],
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

function profileReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_PROFILES:
      return {
        ...state,
        profiles: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case PROFILE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false,
        profile: null
      };
    case CLEAR_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: null,
        repos: []
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default profileReducer;
```

Hoping someone can see where I am going wrong.  My action payload on the redux devtools says that PROFILE_ERROR is running and I get status 400 bad request.

Comment: There is a typo in your model originalname is spelt wrong, that would definetly throw an error

Comment: Thank you have fixed it but that hasn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have played about and now have a solution that works.  Posting it here for anyone else who needs a clue as to how to do this.

Here is the express routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
// bring in normalize to give us a proper url, regardless of what user entered
const normalize = require('normalize-url');
const checkObjectId = require('../../middleware/checkObjectId');


const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');


const Profile = require('../../models/Profile');
const User = require('../../models/User');
const Post = require('../../models/Post');





const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'uploads');
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${new Date().getTime()}_${file.originalname}`);
    }
  }),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/gif' ||  file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype ==='image/jfif') {
      cb(null, true)
  } else {
    cb(new Error('Please upload a file type of jpeg, png or gif'), false)
  }
  }
});


// @route    POST api/profile
// @desc     Create or update user profile
// @access   Private
router.post(
  '/',
  upload.single('file'),
  auth,
  check('location', 'Location is required').not().isEmpty(),
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);

    // destructure the request
    const {
      location,
      bio,
      youtube,
      twitter,
      instagram,
      linkedin,
      facebook,
    } = req.body;



    // build a profile
    const profileFields = {};
    profileFields.user = req.user.id;
    if(req.file !== undefined) {
      let fileUrl = "/" + req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/");
      if (path) profileFields.path = fileUrl;
      if (mimetype) profileFields.mimeType = req.file.mimetype;
      if (originalname) profileFields.orginalName = req.file.originalname;
      if (location) profileFields.location = req.body.location;
      if (bio) profileFields.bio = req.body.bio;
    } else {
      if (location) profileFields.location = req.body.location;
      if (bio) profileFields.bio = req.body.bio;
    }

    
    
   // Build social object
   const socialFields = {youtube, twitter, instagram, linkedin, facebook}


    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(socialFields)) {
      if (value && value.length > 0) 
      socialFields[key] = normalize(value, { forceHttps: true });
    }

    try {
      // Using upsert option (creates new doc if no match is found):
      let profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
        { user: req.user.id },
        { $set: profileFields },
        { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
      );
      return res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

Here is the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  orginalName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  path: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  mimeType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  topics: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'topic',
    }
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

here is the action file

```
// Create or update profile
export const createProfile = (payload, history, edit = false) => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.post('/profile', payload, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert(edit ? 'Profile Updated' : 'Profile Created', 'success'));

    if (!edit) {
      history.push('/dashboard');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the reducer

```
import {
  GET_PROFILE,
  PROFILE_ERROR,
  CLEAR_PROFILE,
  GET_PROFILES,
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  profile: null,
  profiles: [],
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

function profileReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_PROFILES:
      return {
        ...state,
        profiles: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case PROFILE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false,
        profile: null
      };
    case CLEAR_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default profileReducer;
```

Here is the upload component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createProfile, getCurrentProfile } from '../../actions/profile';

const CreateProfile = ({
    createProfile,
    getCurrentProfile,
    profile: { profile, loading },
    history
}) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        location: '',
        bio: '',
        twitter: '',
        facebook: '',
        linkedin: '',
        youtube: '',
        instagram: ''
    });

    const [file, setFile] = useState("");
    const [imageName, setImageName] = useState("Choose file");

    const [displaySocialInputs, toggleSocialInputs] = useState(false);

    const {
        location,
        bio,
        twitter,
        facebook,
        linkedin,
        youtube,
        instagram
    } = formData;

    const onFileChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setImageName(e.target.files[0].name);
    }

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const payload = new FormData();
        payload.append("file", file);
        payload.append("location", formData.location);
        payload.append("bio", formData.bio);
        payload.append("twitter", formData.twitter);
        payload.append("facebook", formData.facebook);
        payload.append("linkedin", formData.linkedin);
        payload.append("youtube", formData.youtube);
        payload.append("instagram", formData.instagram);

        createProfile(payload, history);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentProfile();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [getCurrentProfile]);



    return loading && profile === null ? (
        <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
    ) : (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className='large text-primary'>Create Your Profile</h1>
            <p className='lead'>
                <i className='fas fa-user' /> Let's get some information to make your
                profile stand out
            </p>
            <small>* = required field</small>
            <form className='form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Location'
                        name='location'
                        value={location}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                    />
                    <small className='form-text'>
                        City (eg. Glasgow)
                    </small>
                </div>
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <textarea
                        placeholder='A short bio of yourself'
                        name='bio'
                        value={bio}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                    />
                    <small className='form-text'>Tell us a little about yourself</small>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="image">Upload Profile Image</label><br></br>
                    <input type="file" onChange={(e) => onFileChange(e)} accept="image/*" />
                </div>

                <div className='my-2'>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => toggleSocialInputs(!displaySocialInputs)}
                        type='button'
                        className='btn btn-light'
                    >
                        Add Social Network Links
                    </button>
                    <span>Optional</span>
                </div>
                {displaySocialInputs && (
                    <Fragment>
                        <div className='form-group social-input'>
                            <i className='fab fa-twitter fa-2x' />
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Twitter URL'
                                name='twitter'
                                value={twitter}
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='form-group social-input'>
                            <i className='fab fa-facebook fa-2x' />
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Facebook URL'
                                name='facebook'
                                value={facebook}
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='form-group social-input'>
                            <i className='fab fa-youtube fa-2x' />
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='YouTube URL'
                                name='youtube'
                                value={youtube}
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='form-group social-input'>
                            <i className='fab fa-linkedin fa-2x' />
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Linkedin URL'
                                name='linkedin'
                                value={linkedin}
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='form-group social-input'>
                            <i className='fab fa-instagram fa-2x' />
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Instagram URL'
                                name='instagram'
                                value={instagram}
                                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Fragment>
                )}

                <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-1' />
                <Link className='btn btn-light my-1' to='/dashboard'>
                    Go Back
                </Link>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    );
};




CreateProfile.propTypes = {
    createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    profile: state.profile
});






export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createProfile, getCurrentProfile })(withRouter(CreateProfile));
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar issue